# How to setup Intel IPP with Cmake in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, cmake, intel-ipp

After installing Intel Performance Library (IPP) on Windows 10 a new option appears in `Visual Studio -> Properties` called **Intel Performance Libraries**. This makes it very easy to add IPP to a project.

Is there a way to adjust settings here with Cmake?

Answer (score 1):

To enable IPP in VS project you can use the built-in property `VS_GLOBAL_UseIntelIPP` of a target.

You can define the following macro and use it for all the targets:

```
macro(setup_intel_ipp_windows TARGET_NAME)
 if(MSVC)
  set_target_properties(${TARGET_NAME} PROPERTIES VS_GLOBAL_UseIntelIPP "Sequential") # Parallel_Static
 endif(MSVC)
endmacro(setup_intel_ipp_windows)
```

Comment: This is the only hit on the whole internet for the term VS_GLOBAL_UseIntelIPP - and I can't get it to work? Is the option name here definitely right :)

Comment: Ah - I found out how to deduce this - the name seems to have changed - this works for us:         set_target_properties(${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTIES VS_GLOBAL_UseIntelIPP1A "Static_Library")